# Django Transaction By Column Value

Tags: django, transactions

I'm running a bunch of async workers, and want to create a transaction via:

**UPDATE**

I want to ensure that:

Two aysnc workers aren't overwriting the same ride

and

Two async workers aren't assigning a car to the same ride

```
def my_func(ride_id):
    ride = Ride.objects.get(id=ride_id)
    if not ride.driver_id:
        with transaction.atomic():
            driver_id = find_best_driver_not_assigned() # this could return same driver in two different workers
            # This code executes inside a transaction.
            ride.driver_id = 1
            ride.save()
```

The driver_id column originally stays blank. But whoever "wins", or updates the field, should prevent any other writes from other async celery workers.

The issue is that this `ride` entry's `route` field is being updated every second, and I only want an exception if someone is trying to update the `driver_id` field.

Will this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that won't work because you've put your `driver_id` check outside of the transaction.

Fortunately, you don't need transactions at all for this, since you can accomplish a get-and-set atomically in Django / SQL:

```
is_new_driver = Ride.objects.filter(id=ride_id, driver_id=None).update(driver_id=1)
```

That will atomically set `driver_id` if it wasn't already set, and you can use the return value to determine whether or not that was the case. See the [documentation for `update()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update), which notes:

> Using `update()` also prevents a race condition wherein something might change in your database in the short period of time between loading the object and calling `save()`.

Comment: This is awesome ! Thanks

Comment: What exceptions should I be catching? One if the filter fails and another if the update fails ?

Comment: @DaynaJuliana: Happy to help. There aren't any exceptions to catch - the return value will simply be `0` or `1` depending on whether or not the `driver_id` already exists or not. (Well, `DatabaseErrors` are possible with any query, but there's nothing special about `filter()` and `update()` in that regard.)

Comment: If the driver id exists, wouldn'tI be trying to update a null value?

Comment: @DaynaJuliana: No. If the `driver_id` exists, the `filter()` clause will match 0 rows, 0 rows will be updated, and the return value will be `0`. None of those things are errors.

Comment: Oh and last thing. I also want to ensure two separate workers aren't assigning the same car to a different ride at the same time. Can that be done with this method as well?

Comment: @DaynaJuliana: Probably. This should work anyplace where you need to check-and-set a database column atomically.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105314/discussion-between-daynajuliana-and-kevin-christopher-henry).

Comment: This isn't actually saving. Should I commit on save ?